# How can I imitate Stack Overflows SSO? Particularly where it federates with serverfault.com?

Tags: openid, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, adfs2.0

How does Stack Overflow's SSO work?  ... whatever it is they are doing it seems to work for all sites in the network.

I'd like to learn what Stack is doing so I can see if it's possible to get a similar registration scheme between http://perfmon.com and http://eventvwr.com under ADFS.   I understand that SAML and OpenID are different animals, but the concept of transparent registration should be the same.

**Q:** How does Stackoverflow "federate" with the other sites such as serverfault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenID, One Year Later](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/) on SO blog explains how do they solve the problem.

Also, there is a post on the new [Global Login Mechanism](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) on the SO blog.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't.  It just explains how you can login with openid on all the sites and they match your accounts, not how they're doing the javascript stuff behind the scenes to log you in on superuser.com if you are already logged into stackoverflow (for example).

Comment: @AskBjørnHansen: Actually, my answer is from a few days before this mechanism was introduced (or at least, before the blog post about that). I have edited my answer to include the new blog post.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that – thanks for editing and making the site better!

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow, [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) and [Superuser](http://superuser.com) are part of the [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) network.

So I imagine they have access to each other's members profiles (via direct database access, an API, or otherwise).

Doctype.com is owned by litmus and therefore not managed by Stackexchange.

Comment: I see... it would be nice to get a better understanding how StackExchange does its authentication

Comment: Doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).