# SAML in Stack Overflow?

Tags: saml

Does Stack Overflow use SAML2.0 for Single Sign-On(SSO) services from sites like google,yahoo,etc..,. 
In Google Chrome, I analysed the network and didnt find any request or response containing SAML details.

Answer (score 1):

No, they use OpenID or other proprietary SSO protocols based on frameworks such as OAuth.

This is mostly the same as this question: [How can I imitate Stack Overflows SSO? Particularly where it federates with serverfault.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654654/how-can-i-imitate-stack-overflows-sso-particularly-where-it-federates-with-serv)