# When using LightOpenId I get a different identity if using www

Tags: openid, facebook-oauth, google-openid, lightopenid

When authenticating my users via LightOpenId, I'm getting a different identity if they access the site using http://www.example.com or when they access via http://example.com. Is there any way to avoid this.

Also, I'm planning on also allowing authentication via Facebook, and last time I remember they were using some other method that doesn't return an identity but a token. Because of this, would it just be a better idea to use the email address as a unique identifier, to make both Facebook and Google logins based on the same value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same realm set for both domains, such as:

```
$openid = new LightOpenID('www.example.com');
```

If you use different realms (domains), it is valid for a provider to return different identities, as Google does, for example.

Also, you *can't* rely on the email address returned by OpenID without further verification. From the protocol point of view, it's just a string value that's filled with whatever the user wants.

And lastly - don't limit your OpenID support to Google. The protocol was specifically designed to make it easy to be decentralized, and it isn't much harder to at least provide a way to enter any openid url, instead of just clicking "sign in with google".

Comment: But what is the user types in "example.com" and not "www.example.com" ? In that case it wouldn't work. That's the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: It would work. Why wouldn't it? The user would go to example.com, but example.com would start authentication process for www.example.com. That would, of course, result in the user returning to www.example.com instead of the former, but in this case, it shouldn't be a problem. If you need a solution for multiple independent domains, try searching for [information on how does StackOverflow do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654654/how-can-i-imitate-stack-overflows-sso-particularly-where-it-federates-with-serv/3658650#3658650).

Comment: I've tested this (using authentication with Google) and it returns different identities. I've tried setting a same realm parameter but this doesn't fix this either.

Comment: Well, I've tested this just now, and it does return the same identity for the same realm, regardless of the domain used for the first request. Besides, if I recall correctly, it would be against the OpenID specification to return different identities for the same user and realm combination, so I doubt Google would do that. Maybe something's wrong with your test?